# HTML5 validation fail using AngularJS expression in href attribute

Tags: html, angularjs

The code:

```
<a ng-repeat="..." href="{{...}}"></a>
```

I am using a plugin that requires the href attribute, so `data-ng-href` can't be used :(

Is there an alternative to keeping an AngularJS expression inside a `href` attribute, and have it validate under the W3C HTML5 validator? Thanks in advance, will mark answer as correct :)

Comment: Unless it's an absolute requirement, I wouldn't be too concerned about the standards validity of Angular templates. Strictly speaking, they aren't actually HTML5, but Angular's extension of its functionality. As far as I'm aware Angular is not designed to allow this sort of conformation.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If you want, feel free to add your comment as an actual answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: No worries, I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's an absolute requirement, I wouldn't be too concerned about the standards validity of Angular templates. Strictly speaking, they aren't actually HTML5, but Angular's extension of its functionality. As far as I'm aware Angular is not designed to allow this sort of conformation. I think you'd be best just to leave validation behind.

Answer (score 1):

Another opinion here, 
 using data-ng-href will still produce an href once the template has been initialized, so perhaps your plugin can run once the template is ready? Here is the relevant code right from the angular docs:

```
<a id="link-3" ng-href="/{{'123'}}">link 3</a> (link, reload!)<br />
```

becomes

```
<a id="link-3" ng-href="/123" href="/123">link 3</a>
```

on the page.

ref - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

I personally really like the fact that one can use angular and still have valid html5-